# Can't load bitmap, ALLEGRO C++ CODEBLOCKS

Tags: c++, bitmap, load, codeblocks, allegro

My problem is I can't load bitmap to allegro after compiling windows stops working. I tried different bitmaps with different color depths but it still doesn't work.

```
#include <allegro.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  allegro_init();
  install_keyboard();

  set_color_depth(16);
  set_gfx_mode(GFX_AUTODETECT_WINDOWED, 800, 600, 0,0);
  set_window_title("The Game");

  BITMAP *bmp = create_bitmap(800,600);
  clear_bitmap(bmp);
  BITMAP *BG = load_bitmap("tlotlo.bmp",NULL);

  while(!key[KEY_ESC])
  {
  blit(bmp, screen, 0,0,0,0, bmp->w, bmp->h);
  blit(BG, bmp, 0,0,0,0, BG->w, BG->h);
  }

  destroy_bitmap(bmp);
  destroy_bitmap(BG);


  return 0;


}
END_OF_MAIN();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `set_color_depth(desktop_color_depth())`
2. You aren't checking return codes. If `create_bitmap` or `load_bitmap` fail, they will return `NULL` and you'll need to deal with that accordingly.
3. Loading a bitmap will fail if you aren't in the proper directory. You can test that out by using a full path to the bitmap. If a full path fixes the problem, then you should reconfigure your IDE to work properly.
4. It's possible that the BMP file is not supported by Allegro. Allegro 4's BMP loading code cannot load more "modern" versions of the format. If you're just getting started, you should really use Allegro 5 instead.